# Magento $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') not displaying the menu

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am working on a redevelopment of a Magento site.

I try to display the menu, and i use this in :

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu'); ?>
```

In the page.xml the reference is:

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">

            <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                <label>Navigation Bar</label>
            </block>

 </block>
```

Why the menu is not displayed I don't know..

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It must be like this way in `page.xml` :

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
   <label>Navigation Bar</label>
   <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
</block>
```

Comment: This will display in header

Comment: Hey thanks again. But I don't have the topmenu.phtml file. I don't know how the menu was displayed before.

Comment: you can check in the header. How menu was showing. may be they are using some custom template or something else. Code that I have shared with you is defult magento code for showing top navigation in header

Comment: Yesm I found that in the header the menu items are taken dinamically and I used that code to display the menu. Thanks again for your help.